# Add a Header Row To Excel File through File Helpers

Tags: c#, .net, filehelpers

I am following [this example](http://filehelpers.com/) but I don't know how to make a header row in the final outputed excel file.

Comment: Your link is to the main FileHelpers page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide a 'template' Excel file with just the headers.

```
// Class record
[DelimitedRecord("|")]
public class MyClass
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public int Field2 { get; set; }
    public string Field3 { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // create some data to export
        MyClass[] rows = new MyClass[2] { 
          new MyClass() { Field1 = "Apples",  Field2 = 23, Field3 = "Yes" },
          new MyClass() { Field1 = "Oranges", Field2 = 17, Field3 = "No"} 
        };

        ExcelStorage provider = new ExcelStorage(typeof(MyClass));
        // Set the destination Excel spreadsheet
        provider.FileName = @"MyClass.xlsx";

        // Template.xlsx contains just the column headers on row 1
        provider.TemplateFile = @"Template.xlsx"; 
        // StartRow is after the header row
        provider.StartRow = 2; 

        provider.OverrideFile = true;
        provider.InsertRecords(rows);
    }
}
```

Comment: So I have to have another excel file with just the headers in it? It can't figure out based on the fields?

Comment: That's correct.  The current (2.9.9) implementation of `ExcelStorage.InsertRecords()` does not generate any headers.